# How to track state when iterating in Python's Mako Templates

Tags: python, templates, mako

I want to loop over a list and print the elements seperated by ',', with no trailing comma. I can't just `', '.join(headings)` because of the formating and escaping. But the following obviously leaves me with a trailing comma.

```
% for x in headings:
  <a href='#${x|u}'>${x}</a>, \
% endfor
```

Or more generally: When iterating over something in a Mako template, is there a way to know  if I reached the last element (or first, or nt)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do stuff like this:

```
<%def name="format( item )"><a href="#${item|u}">${item|u}</a>
</%def>

${', '.join( format(item) for item in l)}
```

Comment: Any Idea how to call the build-in formats such as HTML escaping (`|u`, etc.) from your own functions?

Answer (score 4):

To keep track of the first or last leg through the loop, in Mako like in plain Python, use:

```
% for i, x in enumerate(headings):
```

so `i` is 0 on the first leg and `len(headings) - 1` on the last leg.

Answer (score 3):

Extending on @AlexMartelli's answer, I like to couple the `enumerate` thing with a nice trick to keep the instruction small:

```
% for i, x in enumerate(xs):
  ${','*bool(i)} ${x}
% endfor
```